# Boolean convention with "has" prefix in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, naming-conventions

I have a class called Order.
A order can have or not, customs to be paid (for a worlwide transport for instance).
I think fo a boolean called has_customs.
Is it a good practice to name boolean with "has" prefix in Ruby/Rails?

Comment: Ruby convention on this is to postfix the method with a question mark: `has_customs?`

Answer (score 5):

I would advise you to follow the RuboCop guide style : https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop

For boolean naming convention, it is advised to remove all prefixes (e.g. `has_` 
`is_`...) but to end it with a question mark `?`. So in your case it would be `customs?`

Here are the related docs : 
https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/cops_naming/#namingpredicatename
https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-qmark

Comment: I'd never use `is_` or `does_` but I'd usually keep `has_`. Think of `earth.has_moon?` vs. `phobos.moon?`. The former checks whether Earth _has_ a moon whereas the latter checks if Phobos _is_ a moon. Removing all prefixes can result in ambiguous predicate methods.

Comment: @Stefan as a general rule of thumb maybe, but think of how `animal.a?(Cat)` would sound vs `animal.is_a?(Cat)` or `worker.does_work?` vs. `worker.works?` the latter makes it sound like the `worker` could be broken ("not work") however the former makes it clear we are checking whether or not the `worker` actually performs work. There are use cases for all of theses prefixes if they lend to readability and understanding.

Comment: @engineersmnky okay, there might be exceptions. But `is_a?` is a special case to me. And `worker.does_work?` seems a bit contrived. An actual method would probably be called `worker.performing?`, `worker.active?` or `worker.busy?`.

Comment: @Stefan I will agree with "a bit contrived" (although your counter suggestions imply that it is currently doing work, rather than whether or not it ever does work) my point was more to the fact that a) style guides are just *guides*; b) prefixing a boolean method can lend to making it more readable which is a cornerstone of ruby code. So I certainly would not turn my nose up at something like `ruby.is_awesome?`  and would honestly probably prefer it over `ruby.awesome?`

Comment: The advantage of use `has_` predicate is to be able to use rspec predicate matchers.
In this context, `expect(obj).to have_foo` is much better than `expect(obj).to be_foo`

Comment: @engineersmnky I would prefer `ruby.awesome?`  over `ruby.is_awesome?`. I feel like `is_` is implied by the question mark. Also rspec syntax also sounds great without `is_` `expect(ruby).to be_awesome`

Comment: @rubyprince what do you mean "rspec syntax sounds great without is". "Is" is a be verb rspec uses `be_` instead to assist in readability instead your proposal would be more like `expect(ruby).to awesome`

Comment: @engineersmnky hmm, yeah, RSpec was a bad example as it is tailored to the ruby idioms, but I still prefer `ruby.awesome?` over `ruby.is_awesome?`. Maybe it is more due to my familiarity to Ruby idioms.

Answer (score 2):

`has_foo?` is fine. For example, the `Hash` class has an instance_method `has_key?`. You should always append a question mark at the method name if that method returns `true` or `false`.